# Pycharm/Pytorch: finding usages of nn.Module.forward

Tags: pycharm, ide, pytorch

[image: error message when pycharm cant find callers]

Then you click no, and it only finds explicit mentions of `.forward` in the code, rather than model(x) calls. If you click yes, it finds explicit mentions of forward in the pytorch source. Is this fixable? Is there another IDE that supports this?

Pycharm Version:

```
PyCharm 2019.3.3 (Professional Edition)
Runtime version: 11.0.5+10-b520.38 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.1
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 725M
Cores: 12
Registry: 
Non-Bundled Plugins: Key promoter, mobi.hsz.idea.latex, name.kropp.intellij.makefile, net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv
```

Comment: `model(x)` calls `.forward` inside the `__call__`, but not necessarily. Checking other methods that use a specific one and tracking this broader "tree" of usage may not be feasible, therefore I suppose no IDE will provide you with that. BTW, I don't think this is an issue that needs _fixing_. This is a feature that you would like to have.